# How to convert a Stake Key Address from hash to BECH32?

Tags: staking, address, cardano-serialization-lib, cardano-address, public-key

I have this Stake Key:

https://testnet.cardanoscan.io/stakekey/7622b4611b15441e7e15cba128ff999ad72388aeb267adc6e70cc9bc?tab=stakehistory

I want to convert from `7622b4611b15441e7e15cba128ff999ad72388aeb267adc6e70cc9bc` to `stake_test1upmz9drprv25g8n7zh96z28lnxddwgug46ex0twxuuxvn0qp3cptz` format.

How do I do it using this library https://github.com/Emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The beech32 representation is a bit tricky, but you can do it like this:

```
const stakeKey = StakeCredential.from_bytes(from_hex('7622b4611b15441e7e15cba128ff999ad72388aeb267adc6e70cc9bc'));
const networkId = 1; // testnet = 1, mainnet = 0
const beech32StakeKey = RewardAddress.new(networkId, stakeKey).to_address().to_bech32();
console.log(beech32StakeKey);
```

Hope this helps. The "from_hex" function is just a simple js function to convert the Hex string into an UInt8Array that is needed for the from_bytes function of StakeCredentials.